# How to insert data into an Object

Tags: c#

I have the following class file where all properties are defined as follows

```
public class DataDto
{
    public ImmutableList<string> Header;

    public ImmutableList<ImmutableList<string> Rows;
}
```

I would like to add values to the to both properties but I do not know how to do that. I am learning c# and would like to know how to do that. In my program.cs file I am doing the following but I get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception

```
        var mydata = new DataDto();

        var headerList = new List<string>();
        var rowList = new List<string>();
        headerList.Add("1");
        headerList.Add("2");
        headerList.Add("3");

        rowList.Add("4");
        rowList.Add("5");
        rowList.Add("6");

        mydata.Header.AddRange(headerList);
        
        foreach (var value in mydata.Header)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

I would also like to fill in the rows as well with the object.

Comment: You are saying you are learning so i need to ask you this, Is there a specific reason you are using `ImmutableList` over a simple `List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate `Header` and `Rows` properties in your `DataDto` class before you can actually add values to these lists.

Another thing to note is that when using `ImmutableList` the `Add`, `Remove` operations return a new list, hence the immutability.

You could change your code to something like:

```
var myData = new DataDto();

var headerList = new List<string>();
headerList.Add("1");
headerList.Add("2");
headerList.Add("3");

myData.Header = ImmutableList.CreateRange<string>(headerList);
```

If you need to add more headers later you could do:

```
myData.Header = myData.Header.Add("4");
```

For the rows you could do:

```
var rows = ImmutableList<ImmutableList<string>>.Empty;
// add a row
var row1data = ImmutableList.Create<string>(new [] {
    "a", "b", "c"
};
rows = rows.Add(row1data);
myData.Rows = rows;
```

If you just want to fix your crash you can change your `DataDto` class to:

```
public class DataDto
{
    public ImmutableList<string> Header = ImmutableList<string>.Empty;

    public ImmutableList<ImmutableList<string>> Rows = ImmutableList<ImmutableList<string>>.Empty;
}
```

Comment: what about adding values to the rows?do you have perhaps an idea how to do as well?

Comment: Added a small sample of how that could be done.